# How do I check if a 1-d tensor is in a list of 1-d tensors?

Tags: if-statement, boolean, tensor, torch

I have a huge list of size 1 torch tensors `list_of_tensors` (all of the same dimension). I want to check if another torch tensor `tensor_to_check` I created is in the list. I want to run an if statement off of it.
When my `list_of_tensors` are 1 dimensional, then the statement

```
if tensor_to_check in list_of_tensors:
  do something
```

executes perfectly. However, when my `list_of_tensors` have dimension bigger than 1, I get the following error

> Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

I tried

```
if tensor_to_check in set(list_of_tensors):
  do something
```

then even the dimension 1 check fails.

I get the same error if I try torch.isin(tensor_to_check, torch.stack(list_of_tensors))

How do I get around this? What's the fastest way of doing this for all dimensions?